# Pipe with ngModel

Tags: angular, angular5

I am applying date pipe on a Input element

```
<div class="section">
  <h6 style="font-weight:bold">From Date</h6>
    <input [(ngModel)]="Schedule.FromDate | date:'fullDate'" type="text"  class="datepicker">
</div>
```

But it did not work , after some searching I found a post on stack overflow and I changed it to

```
<input [(ngModel)]="Schedule.FromDate | date:'fullDate'" (ngModelChange)="Schedule.FromDate = $event" type="text"  class="datepicker">
```

Now after adding

```
(ngModelChange)="Schedule.FromDate = $event"
```

it show error that

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>   Parser Error: Cannot have a pipe in an action expression at column 21 in [Schedule.FromDate | date:'fullDate'=$event] in ng:///AppModule/UpdateScheduleComponent.html@39:19

FromDate is a Date field in Schedule Interface

```
 FromDate: Date;
```

How can I apply pipes on Input element with [(ngModel)]

I am using angular 5 with Material css

Answer (score 3):

Simply change the two-way ngModel binding to a one-way binding `[ngModel]="(Schedule.FromDate | date:'fullDate')"` (ngModelChange) takes care of the two-way binding part.

[**Demo Here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gsnc2b?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Cant , its two way binding , Its a update page where I can change the date and save value

Comment: Have you tried it? I could make the relevant part of my answer bold if this makes it easier for you to read.

Comment: I tried now it does not show value , a blank Input field , Looks like not binding model to Input

Comment: Someone even made a demo for you :(

Comment: and someone actually implementing it , with no effect

Comment: do I need to cast the value to datetime when I am getting it from api ?

Comment: When saying "taking care of" you mean `(ngModelChange)="object.property = $event"`